# Spring Data Rest Remove orphaned child records

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-rest

I have a unidirectional relation mapped as follows:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, insertable=true)
private List<Child> children= new ArrayList<Child>();
```

The Child is being inlined with no repository and I'm issuing `application/merge-patch+json` to populate as follows:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "key": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Without `orphanRemoval`, this works fine, but if I overwrite the association, I have orphaned records with null FKs pointing back to the parent.  If I add in the orphanRemoval attribute, the request 500s stating:

```
A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I updated nullable to false, and that solves the issue with the cascade, but now I'm not sure how to remove elements from the list.

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution ?